# Swagger doesn't show response body

Tags: swagger-ui

My Swagger endpoint always shows "no content" in the Response Body. Al tough the server sends a meaningful response text back.

[image: swagger UI]

[image: RequestMapping]

[image: DevTools Browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not showing the Response Body is the following parameter in @RequestMapping :   produces = "application/json"

I removed "produces = "application/json" and the response body is shown correctly

Comment: thanks for answering, it solved my issue and saved me, I was working on filter servlet, my issue was I was not setting content-type header